# What does "numeric precision radix" mean in the SQL Server metadata?

Tags: sql-server, radix

I am browsing the SQL Server Management Studio Object Explorer: the metadata. Under the TempDb > Views > System Views > Columns object I find: "Numeric Precision Radix". I know what radix means (binary, decimal, hexidecimal, etc) and what Numeric Precision means (how many digits are in the representation of the number, and Scale: how many digits are after the radix point).

But how can the metadata *itself* (Numeric Precision) have a *Radix* (system of encoding)? It is like saying what color is the CAN of paint?

And why can't I find a description of this phrase anywhere? Thank you.

Comment: Actually you can find the "description" in BOL: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe that `Numeric_Precision_Radix` is specified in the Information_Schema.Columns table as specified by the SQL-99 standard.

It will be different for each DBMS.
according to this [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/infoschema-columns.html) it is specified as:

> If data_type identifies a numeric type, this column indicates in which
>   base the values in the columns numeric_precision and numeric_scale are
>   expressed. The  value is either 2 or 10. For all other data types,
>   this column is null.

For SQL Server it is 10 for `int`, `money` and `decimal` and 2 for `float` & `real`. See below for example where for float where the radix is 2 and the precision is 53, meaning that the it is precise to 53 bits of information.

In other words for int precision is expressed in terms 10 to the power of 10 but for real it is expressed as 2 to the power of 53.

See wiki [link here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf95fa/3)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MyRadix
(
    aInt int,
    bFloat float,
    cMoney Money,
    dDecimal Decimal(12,10),
    eReal Real
)
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX, NUMERIC_PRECISION, NUMERIC_SCALE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyRAdix'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf95fa/3/0)**:

```
| COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE | NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX | NUMERIC_PRECISION | NUMERIC_SCALE |
|-------------|-----------|-------------------------|-------------------|---------------|
|        aInt |       int |                      10 |                10 |             0 |
|      bFloat |     float |                       2 |                53 |        (null) |
|      cMoney |     money |                      10 |                19 |             4 |
|    dDecimal |   decimal |                      10 |                12 |            10 |
|       eReal |      real |                       2 |                24 |        (null) |
```

Comment: Wow. People have way too much to think about. I guess I thought it was inherent that Decimal meant base 10 and Float meant base 2. Are there any alternatives, or other sensible scenarios? Is this just gilding the lily? Could there be any Radixes besides 10 and 2? Base 64?

Comment: Base 16 is used extensively everywhere in encoding.
Base 8 as well.
Weekdays are *kinda* base 7.
Time is *kinda* base 60 / base 12.
Degrees can be represented as base 360.

The actual application of these radixes are very interesting, if you want to dive into the rabbit hole. They seem to be rarely implemented; probably for the effort required to get it right and make it useful.

But 16 and 8 are important for nearly everything digital.

Comment: Further - the numeric precision is important because it affects the (huge) number of errors when calculated in binary and bubbled up to decimal.