# Getting numeric precision in case of int datatype of SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, ado.net

I am fetching following details of columns from SQL Server:

```
Size
Precision
Scale
```

But I have noticed that in case of int I am getting 10 as precision but when i did some research, I couldn't find any such thing related to int, and that int datatype have precision of 10 or in SQL Server Management Studio.

So I don't know how 10 is coming as precision in case of int data type.

**Table**:

[image]

**Screenshot**:

[image: Output]

**Code:**

```
String[] columnRestrictions = new String[4];
columnRestrictions[0] = 'MyDb';
columnRestrictions[1] = 'dbo';
columnRestrictions[2] = 'Employee';

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString"))
{
    con.Open();
    var columns = con.GetSchema("Columns", columnRestrictions).AsEnumerable()
         .Select
          (
                 t => new 
                 {
                     Name = t[3].ToString(),
                     Datatype = t.Field<string>("DATA_TYPE"),
                     IsNullable = t.Field<string>("is_nullable"),
                     Size = t.Field<Int32?>("character_maximum_length"),
                     NumericPrecision = t.Field<int?>("NUMERIC_PRECISION"),
                     NumericScale = t.Field<Int32?>("NUMERIC_SCALE")
                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: If you look at the [int datatype](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187745.aspx) you'll see that the largest values it can store require (up to) 10 decimal digits to represent. So if something's insisting on giving a precision for an `int`, it's not an unreasonable answer to provide.

Comment: [*Precision is the number of digits in a number*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190476.aspx), the maximum digits in a 32 bit int is 10.  (and 19 for a bigint)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28836543/284240

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever :So my output is correct as 10 in case of int datatype???

Comment: @TimSchmelter:Sir i would like to ask you 1 thing that why you deleted your answer on my this question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41062636/get-columns-size-along-with-column-name-and-datatype) although it was correct.i was about to mark it as accepted answer but you deleted it

Comment: @Learning: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41100028/284240)? Well, i had no time to investigate further and thought it wouldnt be helpful

Comment: @TimSchmelter:Yes it was helpfull because you have already got an upvote and now you have my vote too and previously you have also deleted 1 answer on my question which was also correct and i was about to upvote and mark it as accepted but you deleted it before that so you lost my valuable vote.Hehe :)

Comment: @damien_the_unbeliever:you guys are awesome in answer and in comments too.thank you so much sir for providing answer in comment.thanks once again

Comment: @alex k: Thank you so much alex sir.you guys are really awesome because you guys can help anyone in your comments too.Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Precision* refers to the number of significant decimal digits a number can represent.

The `int` datatype, like the `int` datatype in C#, can range from `-2147483648` to `2147483647`, so it can have up to 10 significant decimal digits.

The precision of `int` is therefore always 10.

Comment: It is, though it's not very useful. It's only really a useful datum in cases where it can vary, as in the SQL decimal datatype.

Comment: Thank you thank you so much for helping me clearing my doubt.please keep helping like this